# Is vSphere Web Client (Server) available on linux?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

Is vSphere **Web Client (Server)** available on **linux**?

Based on [vSphere 5 Documentation Center](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.install.doc_50/GUID-74AA3EF1-BDF3-4752-89DB-A522CDE30A66.html) it seems to me that only Windows platform is supported.

It would be great not to run Windows in VirtualBox to manage our virtual machines.

Answer (score 2):

The Vsphere web client only requires Flash in Linux browsers.

Note that in Vsphere 5.0, its functionality is still not 100% to that of the desktop client, but in Vsphere 5.1 it is greatly improved.

To login to the web client use this link: [image]:

Comment: OK, so how do I access the server using web browser from OSX?

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues, other than the missing plugin - which means no VM console access from the web client.

Comment: If I access the VMware ESXi 5 server from OSX I get a page from where I can download Window client. Could you be more specific how to access the admin page from web browser?

Comment: wrong answer. If you follow this link, it goes to error as no Web Client Server (sic!) installed. Web Client Server is a special product which is a mediator between your browser (on Linux or on Windows) and Vcenter server.

Answer (score 0):

According to this blog post on [The Sysadmins](http://blog.thesysadmins.co.uk/vmware-vsphere-web-client-console-ubuntu-linux-11-04.html), there is a Linux version of the VMRC plugin for Firefox required to access the remote console using vSphere Web Client on vSphere 5. Even without that plugin, you can still use the vSphere Web Client, although you will not be able to access the remote console, although you may still perform power actions etc.

The chapter in the documentation you referred to is part of the installation process of installing the "server-side" vSphere Web client on vCenter Server on a Windows server, it's not talking about installing the VMRC console plugin itself.

One possible alternative to using vCenter Web Client on Linux would be to use something like [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/) to connect to your vCenter Server and then run the vSphere Client through that. This won't help you manage individual ESXi hosts, however, in case the vCenter Server goes down, so having a contingency plan to run the vSphere Client locally is a good idea. This won't work, however, if you choose to deploy vCenter Server as the Linux-based virtual appliance rather than on a Windows Server.

Comment: vSphere Web Client has a server component which is installed on Windows. It is this component that the question relates to.

Comment: @Graeme Donaldson My mistake. I have edited my response accordingly.

Comment: You're right that the doc is about `e installation process of installing the "server-side" vSphere Web client on vCenter Server on a Windows server`. My vCenter is running on linux and I haven't found anything about web client server add-on on linux server.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium and Firefox wont work anymore.

But you can install the full Google Chrome which has a working and up-to-date version of Flash.
From this answer: [how-to-install-google-chrome-on-ubuntu-14-04](https://askubuntu.com/a/510063/227856).
With Chrome you will be able to open the web client (at least I am).

open a terminal and follow:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

If you want the 64bit version just replace `i386` with `amd64`

If you encounter any errors simply use

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

To run it from terminal use `google-chrome` or hit the super key and search `Google` or `Chrome`

Answer (score -1):

Officially - not supported. Unofficially - just google:
https://www.google.ge/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=vsphere%20client%20linux&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=baff1c3dc51ef83&bpcl=35243188&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1309&bih=675

**You can upgrade to 5.1 for free, where functionality has moved to web based client.**

http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/products/vsphere/vmware-what-is-new-vsphere51.pdf

http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-51-upgrade-guide.pdf

Comment: Please just provide direct links, it is not the point of Server Fault to just say "google it". This is not constructive.